# Yii2 hasMany/via vs. hasMany/viaTable vs. find/joinWith

Tags: activerecord, yii2, relation

I have a many to many relation in Yii2: RecipeUnit - IngredientWeight - Ingredient. In model RecipeUnit:

```
public function getIngredientWeights()
{
    return $this->hasMany(IngredientWeight::className(), ['recipe_unit_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getIngredients()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ingredient::className(), ['id' => 'ingredient_id'])
                ->via('ingredientWeights');
}
```

Using the following code ActiveQuery generates two SQLs instead of one join, and it takes long time (`$model` is a RecipeUnit instance with `id` = 4):

```
$model->getIngredients()->orderBy('sort_order')->limit(1)->one()

SELECT * FROM `dh_ingredient_weight`
    WHERE `recipe_unit_id`=4 (2977 records 57.1 ms)
SELECT * FROM `dh_ingredient`
    WHERE `id` IN ('4', '5', ..., '5536')
    ORDER BY `sort_order` LIMIT 1 (1 record 2.7 ms)
```

The result is the same if I'm using `hasMany`/`viaTable` instead `hasMany`/`via`:

```
public function getIngredients()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ingredient::className(), ['id' => 'ingredient_id'])
                ->viaTable(IngredientWeight::tableName(), ['recipe_unit_id' => 'id']);
}
```

But without hasMany a normal join is generated, running very quickly:

```
public function getIngredients()
{
    return Ingredient::find()->joinWith(['ingredientWeights'])->where([
            '{{%ingredient_weight}}.recipe_unit_id' => $this->id]);
}

SELECT `dh_ingredient`.* FROM `dh_ingredient`
    LEFT JOIN`dh_ingredient_weight`
    ON `dh_ingredient`.`id` = `dh_ingredient_weight`.`ingredient_id`
WHERE `dh_ingredient_weight`.recipe_unit_id=4
ORDER BY `sort_order` LIMIT 1 (1 record 0.2 ms)
```

The question is, is there any disadvantage if the relation is defined as in the last example without `hasMany`/`via`?

Comment: `I have a many to many relation in Yii2: RecipeUnit - IngredientWeight - Ingredient` you wrote, and your join is simple `hasMany` relation. So yea, ofcourse it will be faster. And also in 2nd you are using `LIMIT 1` and in first case same query get's `2977` results. Do your test's right. Sometimes join more effective then loading records with `IN()`.

Comment: I think it's about a `real N to N relation` if there is a switch model (in this example _IngredientWeight_) between two models( _RecipeUnit_ and _Ingredient_). The method `via` just implements this.